# Range.MergeCells in Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab

I am trying to perform a cell merge on an Excel file from Matlab. I don't know anything about this, but tried to use some code I found elsewhere online and adapted it a bit:

```
Excel = actxserver('Excel.Application');
Workbooks = Excel.Workbooks;
Excel.Visible = 0;
Workbook = Excel.Workbooks.Open('C:\Users\path&filename*.xlsx');
for k=1:length(B)-1
    rng = [ExcelCol((k-1)*MaxH+2),num2str(1),':',ExcelCol(k*MaxH+2),num2str(1)];
    procrng = [rng{:}];
    Range = Excel.Range(procrng);
    Range.Select;
    Range.MergeCells = True;
    Range.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter;
end
```

ExcelCol is a user-defined function I found online that converts column number to Excel alphabet notation. It works - no doubt about it.

But when I run & step through the code, I get an error at Range.MergeCells = True. I get: "Undefined function or variable True'.

Can you please help?

Comment: And worry not: procrng evaluates to something like 'B1:Q1' - so it's legit

Comment: Is it possible to use `Range.Merge`?  That is another way to merge cells from the VBA only side of things.  Not sure why `Range.MergeCells = True` does not work.  It also works in VBA.

Comment: Also, does that same code fail on a empty workbook with no other data in there?  It's possible something is blocking the merged cells like a Table or previously merged cells in the same range.

Comment: `true` not `True`, possibly (don't know if this is meant to be set to a boolean or a string).

Answer (score 0):

Use `Range.MergeCells = true` or `Range.MergeCells = 1`. `True` with a capital T is not a Matlab value.

You'll also need to use `Range.HorizontalAlignment = -4108` instead of `xlCenter` because the ActiveX constants are not exposed to Matlab. There's no good way to get them programmatically; you need to build your own constant table, or do some deep digging with introspection.

You can also use .NET instead of ActiveX to script this Excel stuff from Matlab, and it exposes symbolic constants like `xlCenter` so you can use them (you just have to package-qualify them). But the using Excel automation through the Matlab/.NET interface has some nasty edge-case issues with moving 1-D vectors and having to explicitly cast objects to different interfaces. I can't recommend one over the other at this point.